# How to sort a part of a column text?

Tags: python, flask, flask-admin

I have a `column_default_sort` set to `custom_id` which format is for example `10/K/2019` I want to sort look only for the `10/` part so the letters wouldnt break the number sort, how to set it up in flask-admin?
my current `column_default_sort=('custom_id')`

Answer (score 0):

You can provide a [sort key](https://github.com/flask-admin/flask-admin/issues/190#issuecomment-15128139) for the column using [`column_sortable_list`](https://flask-admin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/mod_model/#flask_admin.model.BaseModelView.column_sortable_list) like so:

```
from sqlalchemy.ext.hybrid import hybrid_property
class MyModel(db.Model):
    @hybrid_property
    def formatted_custom_id(self):
        return self.custom_id[0:2] # Whatever your format is

class MyView(BaseModelView):
    column_sortable_list = (('custom_id', (MyModel.formatted_custom_id,)),)
    column_default_sort = (MyModel.formatted_custom_id, False)
```

Contrary to the documentation, the sort key *must be in a tuple,* even if it's only a single column. That's the `(MyModel.formatted_custom_id,)` portion.

Answer (score -1):

By reading the source code for `BaseModelView`, it's clear that the kind of filtering you need is not supported yet.

Refer to the code below:

```
column_default_sort = None
# Default sort column if no sorting is applied.

# Examples:

class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_default_sort = 'user'
You can use tuple to control ascending descending order. In following example, items will be sorted in descending order:

class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_default_sort = ('user', True)
If you want to sort by more than one column, you can pass a list of tuples:

class MyModelView(BaseModelView):
    column_default_sort = [('name', True), ('last_name', True)]

# Source code reference
def _get_default_order(self):
        """
            Return default sort order
        """
        if self.column_default_sort:
            if isinstance(self.column_default_sort, list):
                return self.column_default_sort
            if isinstance(self.column_default_sort, tuple):
                return [self.column_default_sort]
            else:
                return [(self.column_default_sort, False)]

        return None
```

You have to find a way to circumvent filtering outside of `BaseModelView`.

Comment: It *is* possible to do what OP has asked, so I think it's misleading and unhelpful to say it isn't. The answer also doesn't explain how someone facing this common problem is supposed to resolve it. "Find a way" isn't an answer. :-)